# IIS6 adding space to end of file path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

```
        string filePath = Properties.Settings.Default.audioFilePath.ToString() + " ";
        filePath = filePath.Replace(" ", "");           // iis6 on 2003 server seems to add a space to the end of the path
        string audioFilename = filePath + filename;
        return File(audioFilename, "audio/wav");
```

this is very puzzling to me.  On my dev machine this works fine and the path is correct.  On the production site my IIS6 adds a space to the filePath variable.  I added the line to replace spaces with "" and even added the extra string on my local machine to make sure it was working.

I put a test view in place to pass the path to, on IIS6 I get:

> c:\messages\voicemail\filed\ <

Notice the blank space between \filed\ and < (I added < so I can see the space)

On my dev machine I get

> c:\__dev\_proj\msg\messages\<

I am swapping the path in the web.config file but there are no spaces, and anyway I'm removing spaces, but somewhere when it is served to the browser it seems IIS6 adds the space???  Tried different browsers too, IE and Firefox, both same result so it points to IIS????

Answer: trim was it, and the response that it wasn't a space was dead on.  It was LF.
the fixed code:

```
            string filePath = Properties.Settings.Default.audioFilePath;
        filePath = filePath.TrimEnd();           // iis6 on 2003 server seems to add a space to the end of the path
        string audioFilename = filePath + filename;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sounds very unusual.  But as a work around, rather than using `Replace` you should use `Trim`.  And instead of `filePath + fileName`, try `System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)`.  I don't know if this will suppress the symptoms or not, but it could be worth a shot.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I tried that and it does seem to pinpoint where the problem is, now I get: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
So this is originating in the controller code before the view I believe, so yes, very odd.

Comment: It sounds like the additional character is not a space.  Have you tried finding out what the ASCII code of each character in the audioFilePath is?  Once you find out what the bad character is, you can remove it explicitly.  Or you can take a broader approach of cycling through the characters and only keep permitted characters.

Comment: >c:\messages\voicemail\filed\ <
10 <<< that is the char code, LF is it, but if I was good at following directions and tried trim earlier that was the fix.  So trim takes off LF that was added from the applicationSetting I guess.